# C# операции сравнения и инкримент (++) для типа Enum

Tags: c#, enum, рефлексия

Подскажите, можно ли как нибудь (возможно через рефлексию...) привести Enum (сделать апкаст) к своему типу. Иначе говоря, у меня есть функция которая принимает некое перечисление заране не известно кокое:

```
void myFunc(Enum myEnum)
{
    myEnum++;
    myEnum.CompereTo(cincreteEnumValue);
}
```

Мне нужно выполнить внутри данной функции мне нужно выполнить два действия

1. инкримент (++)
2. Сравнение с каким либо конкретным значением Enum.

Я не совсем пойму как это сделать так как я могу передавать в данный метод любое перечисление. Первое что приходит в голову это сделать апкастинг от базового типа Enum к конкретному перечислению, но я не знаю какое именно перечисление передано. Возможно это можно реализовать через рефлексию ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(myEnum)` - не?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Неа, например:
`enum TestEnum{e_1 = 5, e_2 = 10}` Если я к нему применю `Convert.ToInt32(myEnum)++` то 5 будет = 6, а это не подходит.

Comment: Можно конечно передавать функции увелечитель и стравнитель, но не хотелось бы это делать

Comment: Мне кажется enum... для таких целей... ну такое... Может стоит использовать коллекцию/словарь/массив? Да и вообще по хорошему тут достаточно одного class'a с пару свойств на "борту".

Comment: Зачем же такой непоследовательный enum? А по теме https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105372/how-do-i-enumerate-an-enum-in-c

Comment: @NewView благодарю - думаю то что нужно. 
Касательно не последовательности - примером может быть периоды минут enum Periods {M1=1, M5 = 5, M15 = 15 }

Comment: Возможно, просто обычно с енумами не заморачиваются с последовательностью значений, не к чему это.

Comment: @NewView ожно но можено и так (если в формуле использовать) тогда формула читабельнее выглядить будет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы бы хоть написали в вопросе, чем является в Вашем понимании инкремент для `enum`, ибо я, как и большинство других программистов, понял это так: так как любое `enum`-значение - число, значит, инкрементом для него будет то же, что и инкремент для числа

Однако из комментариев я понял, что Вы ожидаете другого поведения

В общем, как-то так будет выглядеть метод:

```
public enum TestEnum
{
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D
}

public static TEnum NextEnum<TEnum>(TEnum Value) where TEnum : struct, Enum
{
    // Получим все имена для данного перечисления
    // Обращаю Ваше внимание, что они сортируются по своему числовому значению (по возрастанию)
    Array names = Enum.GetNames(typeof(TEnum));

    // Получим имя заданного элемента
    string valueName = Value.ToString();

    // Найдем индекс нашего элемента в массиве
    int valueIndex = names.Cast<string>().Select((x, i) => new { x, i }).First(x => x.x == valueName).i;

    // Вернем следующий элемент 
    return (TEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(TEnum), names.GetValue((valueIndex + 1) % names.Length).ToString());
}

...

// Тест
TestEnum val = TestEnum.A;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    Console.WriteLine(val);
    val = NextEnum(val);
}
```

Вывод:

> A 
>   B 
>   C 
>   D 
>   A

Думаю, это то, что Вам надо

Право, это не будет работать для подобного перечисления:

```
public enum TestEnum
{
    A = 3,
    B = 2,
    C = 1,
    D = 0
}
```

Точнее, будет работать, но не так, как Вы ожидаете, ибо данные об элементах в `enum` все публичные методы возвращают в порядке возрастания их числового эквивалента

Если же Вам это зачем-то все таки надо, то можно прибегнуть к рефлексии, но тут есть 3 жирных **но**:

1. Если Вам это правда нужно, то у Вас какой-то неправильный подход к
   перечислениям, как Вам уже сказали в комментариях
2. Никто не обещает, что компилятор не проведет какой-нибудь шальной
   оптимизации, после которой поля поменяются местами
3. Это удар по производительности

Однако в обучающих целях:

```
public static TEnum NextEnum<TEnum>(TEnum Value) where TEnum : struct, Enum
{
    // Получим все публичные статичные поля типа перечисления
    FieldInfo[] fields = typeof(TEnum).GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

    // Найдем индекс указанного элемента
    string valueName = Value.ToString();
    int valueIndex = fields.Select((x, i) => new { x, i }).First(x => x.x.Name == valueName).i;

    // Получим значение следующего за ним поля
    return (TEnum)fields[(valueIndex + 1) % fields.Length].GetValue(null);
}
```

(Тест и вывод такой-же, дублировать их не буду)

---

По поводу сравнения:

Для `Enum` определен интерфейс `IComparable`, так что ожидаемый Вами метод `CompareTo` там есть (просто Вы его написали неправильно, как и словa *"кокое"*, *"как нибудь"* и другие)

Comment: Я рефлексию в любом случае буду использовать. Мне нужно создать атрибут который будет декорировать определенные поля класса. Далее через рефлексию я буду менять их значения.

Comment: Кстати работает все как нужно, мне и требуется по возрастанию инкрементировать. Я имел ввиду что нумерация может быть не по порядку (как пример писал)

Comment: @JamesBondCaesar: ну, я рад, что смог Вам помочь)